# How To Find Duplicate, Count and Sum Values from different columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, count, mariadb, pivot, pivot-table

I have my table

[image: My Table]

I want to get duplicates from the Name and Status column, count them, and sum values from the Sum column. I want to look like this:

[image: Result]

I am new to SQL so that it may be an easy answer, but I can't seem to find a solution.

This is how far I got, but I can't seem to get the count and sum without errors.

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS recovered 
FROM complaints 
WHERE status = "Recovered" 
GROUP BY name 
HAVING COUNT(name) > 0
```

[myQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MReGL.png)

Comment: You should add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  as tabular text and not as image

Comment: For Pivoting in MariaDB, see See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56670844/1766831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    name,
    sum(status = 'Recovered') recovered,
    sum(status = 'Unrecovered') unrecovered,
    sum(case when status = 'Recovered' then `sum` end) total_recovered_value,
    sum(case when status = 'Unrecovered' then `sum` end) total_unrecovered_value
from mytable
group by name
order by name
```

Side note: `sum` is a language keyword, hence not a good choice for a column name.